# How to concatenate the string of a header (or cell), to the value of another cell?

Tags: r, loops, tidyverse, data-manipulation, data-cleaning

I am cleaning a big dataset, that contains dates (t0:t5 and no_BL:no_48) and test scores (MMSE_BL: MMSE_FU48).

*LONG STORY SHORT,* I need this date: "27-09-12", to look like this "27-09-12_FU24_28",

- where the _FU24 come from a header (columns no_BL : no_FU48).
- and _28 comes from a score value (columns MMSE_BL_MMSE_FU48).

Longer explanation: In this example, I am showing my first 2 rows and 18 columns. Probably the best way to tell you my goal is to show how I would like the outcome to look like:

```
### What I have
cnames <- c("t0", "t1", "t2", "t3", "t4", "t5", "no_BL", "no_FU6", "no_Fu12", "no_FU24", "no_FU36", "no_FU48", "MMSE_BL","MMSE_FU6" ,"MMSE_FU12", "MMSE_FU24", "MMSE_36", "MMSE_FU48")
one <- c("27-09-12", "NA",   "25-07-13", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "27-09-12", "25-07-13", "NA", "29", "NA",  "28",   "28",   "29",   "30")
two <- c("06-11-12", "NA",   "01-10-13", "NA",   "NA",   "NA", "NA",   "NA",   "NA",   "06-11-12", "01-10-13", "NA",   "30",  "NA", "29",   "30",   "30",   "30")

df <- matrix(c(one, two), ncol = 18, byrow = TRUE )  
colnames(df) <- c(cnames)
df <- as.data.frame(df)
View(df)

##### What I need
#OUTCOME
one_ <- c("27-09-12_FU24_28", "NA",   "25-07-13_FU36_29", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "NA", "27-09-12", "25-07-13", "NA", "29",  "NA", "28",   "28",   "29",   "30")
two_ <- c("06-11-12_FU24_30", "NA",   "01-10-13_FU36_30", "NA",   "NA",   "NA", "NA",   "NA",   "NA",   "06-11-12", "01-10-13", "NA", "NA"  ,"30",   "29",   "30",   "30",   "30")

outcome <- matrix(c(one_, two_), ncol = 18, byrow = TRUE )  
colnames(outcome) <- c(cnames)
outcome <- as.data.frame(outcome)
View(outcome)
```

It is a 2 step proccess,

**First** I would like to take the dates contained in columns t0:t5, go through columns no_BL:no_48, find their date match, and attach to the dates from t0:t5 columns the last characters of its date-belonging header.

- For example, "27-09-12" from column t0, is also found in column no_FU24, so I need to attach the last 5 digits of the heather(no_FU24) to the date, looking like this = 27-09-12_FU24.

**Second** after all the first 6 columns are settled, I have to start an iteration again, but this time attaching the scores to the end of the dates.

- For example, "27-09-12_FU24" ends with _FU24, which means that from the column MMSE_FU24 I have to copy the score (28) and attach it to the date value, looking like this at the end = "27-09-12_FU24_28"

I was also contemplating the idea of Header=False, and work with it as a regular row.

Please help! and thank you in advance : )

Comment: Please don’t unnecessarily include tags in the title. The title is supposed to be *succinct*, there’s no need to repeat tags in it to increase the word count.

Comment: hi @KonradRudolph ,  what are the unnecessarily tags from my title?

Comment: @KonradRudolph why would someone would try to increase the word count?

Comment: Exactly, they wouldn’t. ;-) — And as to what constitutes an unnecessary tag, just consider the title with and without “In R,”. The “In R” part isn’t necessary to make the title more readable or grammatical, and it conveys no extra information that isn’t already included in the tags. See also: [Help: What are tags, and how should I use them?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging#:~:text=Should%20I%20use%20tags%20in%20titles?)

Comment: ok @KonradRudolph , now I change it to ´concatenate´ ... this is as succinct as it gets : )

Comment: Would all the `t0` values be present in the same column always? Can it happen that `t0[1]` occurs in `no_FU24` and `t0[2]` occurs in `no_FU36` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree with Ronak's both points here.  Though Ronak has proposed a fantastic answer which I can never imagine, yet I worked on your problem and so I propose alternate solution which is nowhere as good as that answer.  It works

```
df %>% mutate(i = row_number()) %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("t"), names_to = "n", values_to = "v") %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = contains("MM")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(v)) %>%
  rowwise() %>%
  mutate(new = names(.)[which(c_across(1:6) == v)],
         new = str_remove(new, "no_"),
         new2 = case_when(str_detect(name, new) ~ value,
                          TRUE ~ NA_character_),
         v = paste(v, new, new2, sep = "_")) %>%
  filter(!is.na(new2)) %>%
  select(i, n, v) %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = n, values_from = v) %>%
  left_join(df[-c(1:6)] %>% mutate(i = row_number()), by = "i") %>%
  select(-i)

# A tibble: 2 x 14
  t0    t2    no_BL no_FU6 no_Fu12 no_FU24 no_FU36 no_FU48 MMSE_BL MMSE_FU6 MMSE_FU12 MMSE_FU24 MMSE_FU36
  <chr> <chr> <chr> <chr>  <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>   <chr>    <chr>     <chr>     <chr>    
1 27-0~ 25-0~ NA    NA     NA      27-09-~ 25-07-~ NA      29      NA       28        28        29       
2 06-1~ 01-1~ NA    NA     NA      06-11-~ 01-10-~ NA      30      NA       29        30        30       
# ... with 1 more variable: MMSE_FU48 <chr>
```

**Note** Whenver there is sufficient data, the t_cols will automatically find a place in this syntax

modified df

```
> dput(df)
structure(list(t0 = c("27-09-12", "06-11-12"), t1 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_), t2 = c("25-07-13", "01-10-13"), t3 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_), t4 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), t5 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_), no_BL = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), no_FU6 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_), no_Fu12 = c(NA_character_, NA_character_), no_FU24 = c("27-09-12", 
"06-11-12"), no_FU36 = c("25-07-13", "01-10-13"), no_FU48 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_), MMSE_BL = c("29", "30"), MMSE_FU6 = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_), MMSE_FU12 = c("28", "29"), MMSE_FU24 = c("28", 
"30"), MMSE_FU36 = c("29", "30"), MMSE_FU48 = c("30", "30")), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-2L))
```

Comment: hello @AnilGoyal ,  I traced down the row that is giving me trouble! There are a few lines, that the t0:tn date doesn't have a match on the 'no_' side. The error looks like this: 

Error: Problem with `mutate()` input `new`.
x Input `new` can't be recycled to size 1.
i Input `new` is `names(.)[which(c_across(1:8) == v)]`.
i Input `new` must be size 1, not 0.
i Did you mean: `new = list(names(.)[which(c_across(1:8) == v)])` ?

Comment: Instead of 1:8 use `starts_with("t") ` inside c_across. Try

Comment: In that(no match) case, how you'll intend to join the strings?

Comment: works amazingly! thank you @AnilGoyal . Well, the no-match cases are an unexpected mistake in the data collection. I will have to leave them as a date alone, and trace what happened

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of data issues.

1. The 17th column names is `"MMSE_36"` whereas I think it should be `"MMSE_FU36"`.
2. The `NA` values are not actual `NA`'s but string `"NA"`.

I have corrected these two issues below.

```
names(df)[17] <- "MMSE_FU36"
df <- type.convert(df, as.is=  TRUE)
```

We can now create group of column names `t_cols` (`t0`, `t1`, etc) and `no_cols` (`no_BL`, `no_FU6` etc). Use `lapply` over `t_cols` find the matching dates in `no_cols`, get the corresponding `'MMSE'` column from that and paste all these values together.

```
t_cols <- grep('t\\d+', names(df), value = TRUE)
no_cols <- grep('no', names(df), value = TRUE)


df[t_cols] <- lapply(df[t_cols], function(y) {
  if(all(is.na(y))) return(NA)
  col <- names(Filter(function(x) all(x %in% y), df[no_cols]))
  val <- sub('no_', '', col)
  paste(y, val, unlist(df[paste0('MMSE_', val)]), sep = '_')
})

df[t_cols]
#                t0 t1               t2 t3 t4 t5
#1 27-09-12_FU24_28 NA 25-07-13_FU36_29 NA NA NA
#2 06-11-12_FU24_30 NA 01-10-13_FU36_30 NA NA NA
```

Comment: May be I can never figure such a fantastic answer.  Upvoted as always.  Thanks for sharing the knowledge

Comment: Hi @RonakShah ,  Im almost there! when I try to apply it to my normal size data, I get this error: 

Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `MMSE_` doesn't exist.

So then I try df<- df%>% ungroup, run it from the beginning, but still the same error.
In my data I have 8 column for each block, but i dont think that the problem since t_col & no_cols are taking care of it, besides 'no_' dont have the same error. What could it be? :o

Comment: The issue most probably is the column names and the actual data that you have. Try to compare the column names with the data that you have shared with what you actually have. See how they are different. Also check your data with `NA`. Do you have string `"NA"` as shown in your shared data or actual `NA` which can be captured with `is.na` or blanks (`""`).

Comment: I know what happened, there are some rows where the t0:tn don't have a match date on the 'no_' side. (the same thing happen to the answer below from Anil). That's why it worked only a few lines. Is there a way to incorporate this into the code?